# Cannot pull custom event metrics when name has spaces (GA4) Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

We are getting the following error when trying to get data for a custom event.

Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Metric names must only contain letters, numbers, or _. Received a metric name = conversions[New SRP View]

Here is the response from getMetaData endpoint.

```
 {
    deprecatedApiNames: [],
    blockedReasons: [],
    apiName: 'sessionConversionRate:New SRP View',
    uiName: 'Session conversion rate for New SRP View',
    description: 'The percentage of sessions in which a specific conversion event was triggered.',
    type: 'TYPE_FLOAT',
    expression: '',
    customDefinition: false,
    category: 'Session'
  },
```

We have tried replacing the spaces with underscore but no luck.

How can we solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not putting in the correct parameter name

`apiName` after colon `:` ties to a `parameter` name that does not have spaces. (you can not pass event name here)

`uiName` ties to the UI name which can have spaces

---

**How to find the parameter name for my metric?**

1. Go to GA4 UI
2. Navigate to Admin
3. Click Custom definitions
4. Click the Custom metric

Find your metric and click the three dots next to it. The parameter name section value should come after colon `:`

[image]

Comment: Tushar, thanks for your response. These events are already created with space in them. I don't know how that happened but it did happen and I have no control over the names.

Comment: What I am saying is you don't have to add a name, you need to add the parameter name, that's the mistake. Also, under  `apiName: 'sessionConversionRate:New SRP View',` -- New SRP View can't be an event name, it has to be an event paramter

Comment: I did not understand what is your metric name but If it is conversions[New SRP View], you should not use square brackets []